# Help calculating discharge rate from a reservoir as the water level drops?

Tags: civil-engineering, hydraulics, bernoulli

I could do with some help calculating the discharge rate from a reservoir and factoring in how that flow will decrease as the head of water decreases.

The information I have is:

Maximum height of water in the reservoir is: 10.52m

Diameter of the pipe: 0.3m

length of the pipe: 450m

fall of piper from the reservoir to discharge: 14m

I have already calculated the velocity using Hazen-Williams through the pipe using a C value of 140 (cement lined ductile iron pipe) but I'm unsure of how use this and the head of water to calculate the actual discharge rate. I suspect using Bernoulli's would work but I'm unsure as I've confused myself thinking about it so much!

I may have barked up the wrong tree using Hazen-Williams so any help would be appreciated.